# Get something between separators with regular expressions

Tags: regex, bash

I am trying to extract the middle value from a register that is something like this:

```
NAME=PATH=USER=DATE
```

I need to get the path part and all I came up with is this:

```
=[^=]*=
```

the problem is that it includes the = at the beginning and at the end. How could i not include them?

Also, which unix command should I use to extract it? I was thinking sed, but I usually use it to replace strings not to get them. grep maybe?

I am new in bash programming...

Is there any place where I can learn some regex? because I think I will need to really know how to work with them.

Comment: [10 questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3013172/user3013172?tab=questions) with no accepted answer?

Comment: _Is there any place where I can learn some regex?_ -- This makes the question off-topic.  Voting to close.

Comment: Re where to learn about regexes: try http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 3):

Use captured groups:

```
if [[ $str =~ =([^=]+)= ]]
then
    echo "Part between = and = is ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}."
fi
```

Comment: You mustn't double-quote the regex - otheerwise, _literal_ string comparison will occur (applies since `bash` version `3.2`; exception: if `shopt -s compat31` is set). There's a typo in the variable name; should be `BASH_REMATCH`.

Comment: @mklement0 I was waiting for someone to point that out.  Just wanted to see how long does it remain unnoticed :p

Comment: @devnull :) While this answer will be useful once fixed, I'm a little baffled that it got 2 up-votes in its present state.

Comment: @mklement0 Me too.  I actually noticed this after I'd posted an answer.  Pointing out mistakes after posting an answer doesn't seem great to me.  Thought of fixing the problems, but decided against it.  (It shows how people vote.)

Answer (score 2):

In bash:

```
IFS="="
a="NAME=PATH=USER=DATE"
read -a b <<< "$a"
echo "${b[1]}"
```

UPDATE as suggested by mklement0

```
a="NAME=PATH=USER=DATE"
IFS="=" read -a b <<< "$a"
echo "${b[1]}"
```

Comment: +1, but better to directly prepend `IFS="=" ` to the `read` command so as to localize the effect of changing `$IFS`.

Comment: Moreover, you don't necessarily need an array.  `IFS='=' read -r name path _ <<< "$a"; echo "$path"`

Comment: But now that becomes exactly my answer and you get more upvotes. I hate SO `:D`.

Comment: @devnull, Is `_` something like `/dev/null` in this case?

Comment: @Ashkan No, `_` is just an ordinary variable (garbage one in this case) which will capture the remaining part of the line which is or will never be used.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: I hear you; your answer (which got my vote too) still provides value in that it is more detailed.

Comment: @JS웃 It has some special meaning [see](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html) and I was not able to find what happens when we use it like this

Comment: @Ashkan Yes, it has special meaning, so it may be better not to use it as a variable name to avoid confusion; it'll still work, though, and have no unwanted side-effects.

Comment: The value of `_` will be set _after_ the execution of the `read` command, so this has absolutely no unwanted effects. Besides it is the common way of saying _I don't care about this field_.

Comment: @Ashkan In the current context, you could think of `_` as a placeholder that would consume the rest of the input.

Answer (score 2):

So as to have several possibilities, you can also use `read` and make an array with all your fields:

```
var="NAME=PATH=USER=DATE"
IFS== read -r -a var_ary <<< "$var"
echo "field1: ${var_ary[0]}"
echo "field2: ${var_ary[1]}"
echo "field3: ${var_ary[2]}"
echo "field4: ${var_ary[3]}"
```

will output:

```
field1: NAME
field2: PATH
field3: USER
field4: DATE
```

this will also enable you to check that you have the correct number of fields:

```
if ((${#var_ary[@]}==4)); then
    echo "Cool I have 4 fields"
else
    echo "Oh no, I don't have 4 fields (I have ${#var_ary[@]} fields)"
fi
```

Comment: You also demonstrate how to check for the number of fields.  Have my upvote!

Answer (score 2):

No need for complicated regex, a simple `awk` can do it:

```
echo "NAME=PATH=USER=DATE" | awk -F= '{print $2}'
PATH
```

Comment: +1; arguably even simpler (in this limited case): `echo "NAME=PATH=USER=DATE" | cut -d = -f 2` - @devnull had posted this in an answer he's since removed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `bash` parameter to remove the leading and trailing pieces.

```
$ s='NAME=PATH=USER=DATE'
$ s=${s#*=} && echo "${s%%=*}"
PATH
```

`%%` removes the longest match from behind and `#` removes the shortest match from front. Using them together allows you to remove pieces you don't need. You can read more about `bash` parameter expansion [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

Comment: Just a small caveat: `$s` gets modified in the process.

Comment: Absolutely; I should have clarified that _as written_, the input variable is modified.

Comment: Come to think of it: If we also capture the output in a variable like so: `path=$(s=${s#*=} && echo "${s%%=*}")`, the command substitution, due to happening in a _subshell_, would leave the original `$s` untouched (though that may be a tad confusing).

Comment: @mklement0 If you wish to save the variable then you'd do `p=${s#*=} && echo "${p%%=*}"`

Comment: Got it. In your example `$p` is just an _auxiliary_ variable, though; my command substitution example was meant to show how to capture the _result_ in a variable - without the need for an intermediate aux. variable; that said, we can do this with `path=${s#*=} && path=${path%%=*}`, without a subshell.

Comment: Absolutely. Just two different use cases: mere echoing vs. capturing in a variable. I plead guilty to conflating them without saying so, but at least we've now covered them both. :)

Answer (score 1):

NAME=PATH=USER=DATE

Multiple ways to extract this data. The easiest may be pattern filtering. Pattern filtering has four forms:

- `${VAR#PATTERN}` - Remove the **smallest** left most part of the string that matches the pattern.
- `${VAR##PATTERN}` - Remove the **largest** left most part of the string that matches.
- `${VAR%PATTERN}` - Remove the **smallest right most part of the string that matches.
- `${VAR%%PATTERN}` - Remove the **largest** right most part of the string that matches.

You can remember that `#` is to the left of `%` on the keyboard, so `#` is left and `%` is right.

```
STRING="NAME=PATH=USER=DATE"
PATH=${STRING#*=}  # Removes NAME=
PATH=${PATH%%=*}   # Removes =USER=DATE
echo $PATH         # Echoes "PATH"
```

You might be able to use the `read` to get all four at once. I am on an iPad, so I can't test this right now.

```
OLD_IFS="$IFS"
IFS="="
read NAME PATH USER DATE <<<"$STRING"
IFS="$OLDIFS"
```

`$IFS` is thee *Input File Separator* and is set to *space/tab/NL* by default. I save the value of `$IFS` before I change it. I set it to `=` which separates your various values in your input string..

The `read` will read in the values using `$IFS` to separate each one. The `<<<` is a way to get the shell variable in as input.

Once I finish getting the values, I reset `IFS`. Otherwise, I would have problems later on.

Comment: Useful info, but it's better to stay away from all-uppercase variable names to avoid conflicts with environment variables; case in point `$PATH`. You can localize the effect of changing `$IFS`: `IFS="=" read name path user date <<<"STRING"` - no need to save and restore `$IFS` then.

Comment: I usually avoid uppercase variables, but I wanted to make it obvious the names of the variables.

Answer (score 0):

Excellent place to start for regex on Stackoverflow is : [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

For your actual question - you were looking for a regex and a way to use it in bash so:

```
josephs-mbp$more temp.txt 
NAME=PATH=USER=DATE
josephs-mbp$sed 's/^.*=\([^=]*\)=.*=.*$/\1/' temp.txt 
PATH
josephs-mbp$
```

Let's break down the important bit.  Occasionally you want to refer to bits of a regular expression separately, it turns out that the easy way of doing this is by putting things in parenthesis '(' ')'  - but in regex land we have to escape them so it's '(' and ')'. These **make no difference at all to the match** but they make a difference to what happens now.

In general the bit of a regex between a '(' and ')' is stored in a location that can be accessed later with \1, \2,... with the first pair stored in \1 and the second in \2 and so on.  Here I just put the bit of the regex you wanted into the brackets and then replaced (thats the 's/fu/bar' bit) in sed.  It's ugly and there are probably much more effective ways of doing it, but I think you are starting from about the same point I am and I think that this is the next step for you.

Comment: This is wahat i wanted!. But i have a question.
if i "read" the regex i would say something like:
From the beginning of the line(^),any character any number of times(.*) and then an equal sign (=). There i would have gotten just:NAME=
What i don't understand is what you do next, the \( \) part. I've seen this multiple times and i can't get it. I know it has something to do with the /\1 at the end of the expression but i don't quite get it.
The other part (=.*=.*$) would be: from an equal sign(=) any character any numer of times (.*) until it reads an equal (=) and again, any character til EOL

Comment: Thanks @user3013172 glad to help - I've added a bit of an explanation.  Let me know if that clears up nicely. I hope it does - this might be my first ever (none-self) accepted answer on the site... :)