# How to read this regex

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I've been told to use this regex with sed:

```
sed 's/^.*=\([^=]*\)=.*=.*$/\1/'
```

to get the PATH part from:

```
NAME=PATH=USER=DATE
```

If I "read" the regex i would say something like: From the beginning of the line (`^`),any character any number of times (`.*`) and then an equal sign (`=`). There I would have gotten just `NAME=`. What I don't understand is what to read next, the `\( \)` part.

I've seen this multiple times and I know it has something to do with the `/\1` at the end of the expression but I don't quite get it.

The other part (`=.*=.*$`) would be: from an equal sign (`=`) any character any number of times (`.*`) until it reads an equal (`=`) and again, any character until reaching end of line (`$`).

Comment: Try [regex 101](http://regex101.com/). Or [regexper](http://www.regexper.com/#%5E.*%3D%5C(%5B%5E%3D%5D*%5C)%3D.*%3D.*%24).

Comment: [Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/UEWO-TAJ0jeNdFz5)

Comment: @Boris: doesn't work for sed - the `\(` here aren't escaped parens like they are in f.e. perl.

Comment: Why didn't you ask when you got [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23324527/2235132)?  I don't see a reason to make another post for this?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about clarifying one of the response received in [OP's another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23324406/get-something-between-separators-with-regular-expressions).

Answer (score 3):

The `\([^=]*\)` is for capturing the matched part inside the parenthesis. You can then use this match in the second part of the `s///` command as `\1`.

Generally, you can use `\N` to use the `N`th captured partial match or `&` to substitute the complete matched regular expression.

See [Overview of Regular Expression Syntax](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Regular-Expressions) for details of the regular expression used in sed.

Answer (score 1):

the parentheses group the result you wish to capture, in this case "any number of characters which are not the '=' character".  The string matched by the pattern inside the parentheses can be referred to later as \1 -- or \2, \3 etc if there were subsequent groups in parentheses.  the '\' before the parentheses are needed to escape the (,) characters so they are interpreted as grouping symbols -- not certain if they need to be escaped this way for sed or from the shell interpreter reading the expression.

Answer (score 1):

To get the `PATH` i would have used a simple `awk` like this:

```
echo "NAME=PATH=USER=DATE" | awk -F= '{print $2}'
PATH
```

Easy to understand, and work nice.
Device text by `=` and then print second field.

Answer (score 0):

or with `cut`

```
$ echo "NAME=PATH=USER=DATE" | cut -d= -f2
PATH
```

Answer (score -3):

The \s before the brackets are for escaping.

It means, `"The start of the string (^), any character any number of times (.\*), then an equal sign (=), then an opening bracket ('\('), then any character EXCEPT '=', any number of times ([^=]\*), then a closing bracket ('\)'), then an equal sign (=), then any character any number of times (.\*), then an equal sign (=), then any character any number of times (.\*), then the end of the string ($)."`

Comment: Incorrect for sed, the escaped parens are a capture group, not literal parens.

Comment: Damn. I had no idea. Thank you!